# legend location and scale value font size pygal python

Tags: python, svg, graph, pygal

I'm using [`pygal`](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/index.html) to create [half-pie](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/solidgauge.html#half) SVG graph in python.

1. How can I move the legends from left to below/above the half-pie? (like the picture).
2. How can I change the font size of the scale value? (mark in red)

[image: The desired result]